# Exclude javascript files from sonar's "Coverage on new code"

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-coverage

In `SonarQube`, "Coverage on new code" considers `java` and `js` files for my java web applications. Is it possible to exclude `js` files from it?

I'm using:

- `SonarQube-6.7.1` community edition.
- `Jacoco` maven plugin for code-coverage on java codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For jacoco maven plugin just add the configuration to exclude the files as below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.9</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>org/yates/webapp/web/config/*.class</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For SonarQube You can set the `sonar.exclusions` property

```
sonar.exclusions=src/main/java/org/sonar/*
```

Refer the documentation below:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreFiles

UPDATE:

For SONAR coverage exclusions:

```
<properties>
    <sonar.coverage.exclusions>foo/**/*,**/bar/*</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
</properties>
```

Comment: I want to exclude only javascript files from sonar's "Coverage on new code", but not excluding them in sonar analysis.

Comment: The folder structure also matters : for example : **/webapp/**/* will exclude all files under webapp directory. The "**" is for directory and "*" is for file. If you just have **/webapp/* then it won't exclude the folders under webapp folder.